# How to insert "blank character" in WhatsApp?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

There is a blank character (kind of box) that can be used in WhatsApp to set blank status or send blank messages.

How to create/type or find that character?

Answer (score 16):

The methods shared here unfortunately do not work; the Arabic Character used to work but it stopped working since long.
The only character which seemed to work was the Reverse Character Unicode [which I discovered in 2005]  Pasting or Opening it on a PC messes it up.
Afterwards I stumbled on another unicode character which would work (on most devices) even when shared through PC etc.

Copy the Space visible between the bold brackets **[** ‏‏‎ **]** .

If for some reason you fail to copy it from above you may copy it from my blog > [**here**](https://blog.drhack.net/whatsapp-blank-status-message-trick/).

The box type thing you mentioned appears on Apple devices and the proper technique wouldn't result in a box type thing even on Apple devices.

**Fun Fact :** I was the one who worked out the "blank character" thing on the internet more thn 2 yrs back and finding others using(stealing) even "my images" spoils the mood, thus I came here to post the same.

Answer (score 6):

Just copy the character between the quotes: " ", and paste it wherever you want.

Answer (score 5):

Just go to your computer, go to character map (or a word document) and hit <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>255</kbd> or <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>0160</kbd> and copy that file into your phone. Then open that document on your phone, copy the text and paste it wherever you want.

However, if you don't want to waste time doing all this; just go to your WhatsApp settings and hide your status.

Answer (score 3):

## Method 1 – Using Arabic Words

1. Copy this content >> ” ﱞ  “
2. Make sure you have copied the message with (double quotes).
3. Paste this content on WhatsApp.
4. First, try to remove or delete the left quote.
5. Later try to remove or delete the right quote.
6. When you will try to remove the right quote, everything will be gone.
7. Done… Tap on send button to send a blank message.

## Method 2 – Using Alt + Key Combinations

1. Open Notepad on PC or Laptop
2. Press ALT + 255 (Hold Alt Button and Type 255).
3. The above key combinations will generate a blank space.
4. Now save this file on the smartphone (PC > PHONE).
5. Before sending the message, open the file on the phone.
6. Copy the content.
7. Open the WhatsApp and paste the content to send.
8. Done… You have successfully sent a blank message to your friend on WhatsApp.